# I keep getting an extra line when plotting data plt.plot. Any fix?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So im just trying to plot my data but keep getting a persistent extra plot out of nothing. I checked the variable explorer and it doesnt look like there is any extra column or anything. Any help?

```
data=np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\Damping Experiment\Raw Data\Damped\Damped free osccilations raw 2.txt',dtype=None, delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
plt.plot(data[0:,0:2])'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The result of `data[0:,0:2]` is a 2D array with n rows and 2 columns.

And by providing a 2 columned array as a single argument, matplotlib will generate a range of numbers starting from 0 up to number of rows as X-values and plot the given 2 columned as separate Y-values (2 plots).

If you want to plot the first column against the third column you must provide the x and the y values separately.

```
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `plt.plot(data[:,0:2])` to create two lines, the first being `plot(data[:,0])` and the second being `data([:,1])`.

What you might mean is `plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])` which would use the first column as the x-values and the second column as the y.